# Elasticsearch doesn't start after loading to many data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i've loaded over 3 millions documents on a local node in Elasticsearch. At the time, it stopped automatically because of storage ; however, it did still work when using kibana.
I've tried to launch it again and now ES doesn't even start ; it gets stuck on this

[image]

what could I do to launch ES and access the Kibana console ?
or else, how could I reset everything ?

Comment: you should add more disk space. or increase watermark

Comment: By looking at your image, it's clear that Elasticsearch has reached a high disk watermark ie free disk space crossed its high threshold level.

Comment: being new to ES, what is a "watermark" ? how would you inscrease it ?

Comment: Because i'm still at an early stage, i was considering removing all indices and changing my model to have fewer documents hence more space. However, i can't even access the Kibana console and the curl command doesn't work either. I've looked at the link but I can't run anything. Is there a simple to erase this particular index without launching ES ? My last idea would be to inscrease my disk space via Ubuntu.

Comment: @BorisM if you are running it simply with some test data, better you delete the data folder in your elasticsearch directory or where your are writing it(you can define that in elasticsearch.config), I wouldn't suggest increase the disk size as this means this garbage will never be clean up but if its a production data and you cant delete any data then that's very good option :)

Comment: So i've resized my vbox and it works like a charm. I used this if anyone is interested. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Aqx-VHv2_k) [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_UyKufXR3c&t=300s)  ; however, I'd be very interested to know how to delete an index without running ES

Comment: @OpsterElasticsarchNinja, all right perfect ! I was afraid to do that thinking it might create other issues. I'll keep that in mind though. To be thorough, I've increased the disk size and deleted the data to try some new model as there is, indeed, no point on keeping garbage data ;)